# Quick way to generate row numbers in SQL

Tags: sql

I am trying to generate unique row numbers in SQL, e.g. 1,2,3,...n . These row numbers should be unique and non-repeating.

I wrote the following code:

```
select *, row_number() over ((order by (select 1)) as r from original_table;
```

This code runs but it is extremely slow. I tried to only place a few columns (e.g. select col1, col2, col3, row_number() .... ) instead of writing select *, but I am not sure if this will result in non-unique row numbers.

Is there a way to speed it up? I am working with Netezza and there is no GENERATE_SERIES function that can do this.

Comment: Select * will have to read all the columns from table, if you dont use all the columns try and specify column names, that should speed it up to some extent. Also check if order by clause can be skipped in your sql version. so you can use row_number() over() as rn. An inline select might also be affecting the performance

Comment: thank you for your feedback... I just got an error: row number must include order by specification

Comment: Without a meaningful `ORDER BY` in the `OVER` clause, the server might assign different numbers to different rows on different runs of the query.

Comment: What's the business case for this? You could just add an identity or GUID column to the database table; that way each row is assigned a serrogate key. But why?  Will this value be re-used? do you expect the value to be consistant every time or can a row be (1) this time and 123 the next? What's the purpose of this unique value?  Does the unique value need to be availalbe for subsequent queries?  is it one table you want this for or a combined tables and result set?  To help us help you, identify what you're trying to do because there may be other options.  Also what RDBMS?

Comment: Simply put what do you need a unique number?  what problem are you trying to solve and think it will help?  Consider: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

You can try using these two techniques

> If at all feasible, attempt to restrict the number of rows that the row_number() function processes. As an alternative to using SELECT *, you said that you attempted choosing just a few columns. This method minimizes the quantity of data that needs to be sorted and numbered, which makes it a good strategy.

> Rather of employing SELECT *, think about pre-filtering data with a subquery before using the row_number() function. Performance can be enhanced and less data handled as a result. For example:

```
SELECT col1, col2, col3, row_number() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) AS r
FROM (
    SELECT col1, col2, col3
    FROM original_table
    WHERE <conditions>
) AS subquery;
```